# Retrieve GitHub PR Label After Merged

Tags: github, github-actions

I am looking to implement an automated SemVer process.

Is there anyway in GitHub to retrieve the labels of a PR AFTER the PR has been merged?

For example, lets say a PR has a label of **major**, when this PR is merged to main, I want another GH action to run, read the label and then bump the major version tag on the repo.

Is this possible?

Comment: You could trigger on `pull_request`, type `closed`, and inspect `github.event.pull_request.labels`. There are similar questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60710209/3266847) about triggering on merge (vs. close), and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59588605/3266847) about looking at a label. Your question is almost a duplicate of the second one.

Comment: To create the release, you could use https://github.com/rymndhng/release-on-push-action, which lets you specific the bump scheme.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is There Anyway To Retrieve The Label/Tag of a PR After Merged to Main?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78194747/is-there-anyway-to-retrieve-the-label-tag-of-a-pr-after-merged-to-main)